# Merge Two SQL Queries to get Output in Single Table

Tags: sql

I have 2 select queries and getting separate result.
But my requirement is to get combined result of both and return a single result. Result should consists of Agencyid, Agency, abbrev, address count and collaboration count.

```
select a.agencyid,a.name as Agency,a.abbrev,count(aa.agencyid) as no_of_address
from Agency a
left join AgencyAddress aa on aa.agencyid=a.agencyid
group by a.name,a.abbrev,a.agencyid
order by a.name

select a.agencyid,a.name as Agency,a.abbrev,count(c.CollaborationID) as no_of_collaboration
from Agency a
left join Collaboration c on c.AgencyID=a.AgencyID
group by a.name,a.abbrev,a.agencyid
order by a.name
```

Hence I am getting 2 outputs as below:

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luuku.png)

My expected output should be as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W88VY.png)

Comment: Do you mean concatenate the queries? (union all)

Comment: Ask two separate questions.

Comment: I need both `no_of_address` and `no_of_collaboration` in a single table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with this:

```
SELECT T1.AgencyID, T1.Agency, T1.abbrev, no_of_address, no_of_collaboration 
FROM (
    SELECT A.AgencyID,A.Name AS Agency,A.abbrev,COUNT(AA.AgencyID) AS no_of_address
    FROM Agency A
    LEFT JOIN AgencyAddress AA ON AA.agencyid = A.agencyid
    GROUP BY A.Name, A.abbrev, A.agencyid
    ) T1
JOIN (
    SELECT A.AgencyID,A.Name AS Agency,A.abbrev,COUNT(C.CollaborationID) AS no_of_collaboration
    FROM Agency A
    LEFT JOIN Collaboration C ON C.AgencyID = A.AgencyID
    GROUP BY A.Name, A.abbrev, A.agencyid
    ) T2 ON T1.AgencyID = T2.AgencyID
ORDER BY T1.Agency
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do this:

```
SELECT a.agencyid,
       a.name AS Agency,
       a.abbrev,
       aa.no_of_address,
       c.no_of_collaboration
FROM Agency a
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT agencyid,
          count(agencyid) AS no_of_address
   FROM AgencyAddress
   GROUP BY agencyid) aa ON a.agencyid = aa.agencyid
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT agencyid,
          count(agencyid) AS no_of_collaboration
   FROM Collaboration
   GROUP BY agencyid) c ON a.agencyid = c.agencyid
ORDER BY a.name;
```

I think it is more efficient that the other answers.

One more way to achieve this can be:

```
SELECT a.agencyid,
       a.name AS Agency,
       a.abbrev,
  (SELECT count(aa.agencyid)
   FROM AgencyAddress aa
   WHERE aa.agencyid=a.agencyid) AS no_of_address,
  (SELECT count(c.agencyid)
   FROM Collaboration c
   WHERE c.agencyid=a.agencyid) AS no_of_collaboration
FROM Agency a
ORDER BY a.name;
```

This is easier to read but not as efficient as the above one.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT aa.agencyid, aa.name AS Agency, aa.abbrev, no_of_address, no_of_collaboration 
FROM (
    SELECT a.agencyid, a.name AS Agency, a.abbrev, COUNT(a.agencyid) AS no_of_address
    FROM Agency a
    LEFT JOIN AgencyAddress aa ON aa.agencyid=a.agencyid
    GROUP BY a.name, a.abbrev, a.agencyid
    ) aa
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a.agencyid, a.name AS Agency, a.abbrev, COUNT(c.CollaborationID) AS no_of_collaboration
    FROM Agency a
     LEFT JOIN Collaboration c ON c.AgencyID=a.AgencyID
    GROUP BY a.name,a.abbrev,a.agencyid
    ) bb ON aa.agencyid = bb.agencyid AND aa.name = bb.name AND aa.abbrev = bb.abbrev
```

order by aa.name

Like this maybe?

Comment: Removed the order by from the subqueries.

Comment: Now getting this error `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'name'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'name'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'name'.`

Comment: Use aa.Agency instead of aa.name and bb.Agency instead of bb.name